# how to remove specific row from list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array-splice

Altough searched everywhere, could not find a solution 
I have a problem with deleting the **CORRECT** row from the list.

For example I have below array:

```
$scope.rows = [{
        "ID": 12,
        "customer": "abc",
        "image": "abc.jpg",
},{
        "ID": 13,
        "customer": "klm",
        "image": "klm.jpg",
},{
        "ID": 14,
        "customer": "xyz",
        "image": "xyz.jpg",
}];
```

Trying to delete the row where ID = 13 (ID will be received from node server) with the code as follow:

```
        Socket.on('delete', function( ID ) {

            var a = $scope.rows.indexOf(ID);
            $scope.rows.splice(a, 1)

        });
```

But this removes not the correct row.

**How can I specify my parameter to delete the right row like:**

```
remove rows("ID" = ID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` search substring in an array (and not in a relational array)

Try this:

```
var whatIndex = null;
angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(cb, index) {
  if (cb.ID === ID) {
     whatIndex = index;
  }
});

$scope.rows.splice(whatIndex, 1);
```

Comment: This only works if you're trying to remove a single row. Anyone have a solution for removing multiple rows?

Answer (score 2):

Remove an current selected item:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="remove($index)">Remove an item</a>                     //this one is dynamically generated link using ng-repeat

 $scope.remove = function (item) {
        $scope.retrieveddata.splice(item, 1);
    }
```

You can remove the current item using it's index.($scope .retreiveddata is my array list )

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your solution works with delete-buttons. I have NOT buttons but I receive an ID to delete the row(s) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

pass id in this function

```
$scope.deleteCurrentId = function (ID) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.row.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.row[i].id == ID) {
            $scope.row.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

or

```
$scope.deleteCurrentId = function (ID) {
    angular.forEach($scope.row, function (cb, index) {
        if (cb.id == ID) {
            $scope.row.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
};
```